# 1/2" OSB underlayment + Durock VS 3/4" + Durock

Tags: subfloor, underlayment, transition, osb

I am planning my subfloor from the I-Joists up for a new build in my kitchen and living room.  My thought, to minimize the transition between rooms was to lay 3/4" OSB for the living areas, and I am unsure about the kitchen.  I could do 3/4" as well, and add 1/2" durock for tile or 1/4"  But in doing this the transition will be significantly higher with thinset, I wonder if I can get away with 1/2" OSB underlayment and add 1/4"-1/2" durock above it, so the transition will not be as noticeable.

Thoughts please?

Comment: OSB is lousy when exposed to water.  If you are thinking of durock in the kitchen for tile or water protection, forget OSB.  Go with plywood.  Then the question is what is the plan for finished flooring.  That will determine where to go with thickness.  If you plan LVP everywhere you are good with 1/4 durock.

Comment: I don't think there is any such thing as 1/2" OSB underlayment, i.e. sheet goods rated for use as flooring. 5/8" is the minimum.

Comment: What finished flooring are you planning to use?  Ceramic tile usually wants thicker floors, so reading the installation instructions first will be good.  Older tiles usually wanted about 1.5 inch of sub floor before laying down tile.  Unknown if newer tiles are the same.